# No longer able to expand jobs in SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, sql-server-agent

In SSMS on a Windows 7 machine, while connecting to a server running SQL Server 2000, I am no longer able to click on the Jobs to see the Object Explorer Details. Previously, this was not an issue, but it appears to have begun not long after a restart of the SQL Server Agent.

> Failed to retrieve data for this request...
>
> Severity:  11
>   Error Number: 0
>   State: 0

In SQL Server Enterprise Manager on my XP machine, I am able to view the Job details, but it takes a long time; trying to view the properties of an individual Job also takes an inordinate amount of time.

In SSMS, I am not having any trouble opening tables and running queries or opening procs and running them.

Any insight into causes and/or fixes?

*Responses to comments:*

- Connectivity is good.
- *msdb.sysjobhistory* shows about 6500 records, with 90% of the records created in 2014.
- RDP into the 2000 box indicates the same slowness for SQL Server Agent jobs display.
- I do not experience lag time when:

  - I connect to the server
  - I open a table or procedure
  - When I run a basic query
- Whenever I attempt to view the Job Details under SQL Server Agent, the lag time is significant.
- Queries against *msdb.sysjobhistory* and *msdb.sysjobs* run fine in Query Analyzer.